# How to remove super tight sink faucet supply hose nut

Tags: faucet, sink

I am trying to remove this supply line nut but it is on super tight.  and because it is connected to a softer pipe just right below it, the whole thing moves along when I try to unscrew the nut so I can't get much leverage as I'm afraid I might break the whole thing.

Does anyone have any ideas I can try ?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need two adjustable wrenches. Use one to hold the valve body and the other one to turn that nut counterclockwise. The one holding the valve can be supported by holding it against the wall.

Comment: You may be able to position the two wrenches so just squeezing them together will loosen the fitting. Sorry if this doesn't make sense but anyone that's done it knows what I'm talking about.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose  I know exactly what you're talking about but typing it out to explain the procedure would be tough. :-)

Comment: @PlatinumGoose  any way you can show on the picture where I would position the 2 wrenches to loosen the fitting ?  thanks !

Comment: @JACK   the 2 wrench method works!  thanks !  unfortunately I was trying to use the backflow method to clear my clogged kitchen sink single faucet,  and it doesn't work.  Do you know if there any other way to fix the faucet ?   or the only way is to replace the whole thing ?

Comment: @TomHu Try removing and cleaning the aerator at the tip of the faucet spout. If that  doesn't work you might have to remove and clean the cartridge. Make sure to turn off the water before you do this.

Comment: @TomHu That should probably be in a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Notice the way the wrenches are positioned. When you squeeze them together the top nut will turn counter clockwise and the bottom one will turn clockwise. With the top and bottom nuts having six sides and the wrenches having an offset you can usually position them just far enough apart like in the photo. Sometimes you have to flip one or both of the wrenches over so the offset points the other direction. The farther out you squeeze the more leverage you get. [image][image]